# How to add operators in doctrine2 query builder where statement

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Im trying to select from a table where the selected duration divided by the entry duration equals has no remainder.

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
->from('AcmeBlogBundle:Entry', 'e')
->andWhere(":duration % e.duration = 0")
->setParameter('duration', $duration);
```

This returns the error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 226: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '%'
```

This would work in plain SQL. Does anybody know how to do this with Doctrine's query builder?

Answer (score 12):

The symbol `%` is not a DQL operator. Try this:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
->from('AcmeBlogBundle:Entry', 'e')
->andWhere("mod(:duration,e.duration) = 0")
->setParameter('duration', $duration);
```

Or read this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html
The 12.5.1 paragraph.

```
MOD(a, b) - Return a MOD b.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but mod didn't work in the query. I'm looking at the documentation again and it does not list modulus and doesn't even indicate any calculations within the where statements. I'll have to keep looking, but good idea.

Comment: You are a genius. MOS(a,b) worked like a charm. Thank you so very much!