# PHP Doctrine - Select rows where number divided by number has no residue

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

I tried to rewrite "easy" select to Doctrine:

Original query:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE value % 200 = 0;
```

But in doctrine its not work. I have this code in Doctrine:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$queryBuilder->where('u.value%200=0');
```

This fall to:

```
QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 255: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '%'
```

Is there chance to use `%` as operator? Or exists any function for achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040558/how-to-add-operators-in-doctrine2-query-builder-where-statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add operators in doctrine2 query builder where statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040558/how-to-add-operators-in-doctrine2-query-builder-where-statement)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$queryBuilder->where('mod(u.value,200)=0');
```

Works good!